# ¿Como podría "pasar por referencia un valor de tipo int?

Tags: python, paso-por-referencia, paso-por-valor

Estoy diseñando un programa simple que me permita recorrer los nodos de un grafo y contar cada nodo dada su profundidad.
Sin embargo, mi variable **`profundidad`** es un número, por lo que al meterla en otra función, donde su valor es editado, se pasa por valor y necesito que sea por referencia.
Sé que en `Python` no existen esos dos términos. ¿Cómo podría hacer que en la función madre se cambiase el valor de `profundidad`?

```
def recorrer(grafo, nodoVisitar, nivel, cola, visited, profundidad):
    personas = 0
    if profundidad < nivel:
        profundidad += 1
    for s in grafo[nodoVisitar]:
        cola.append([s, profundidad])


    while cola:
        v = cola.popleft()

        if not visited[v[0]]:
            visited[v[0]] = True
            personas += 1

        if v[1] < nivel:
            personas += recorrer(grafo, v, nivel, cola, visited, v[1])

    return personas

def resultado(grafo, n):
    cola = deque()
    persona = 0
    profundidad = 1

    visited = [False] * len(grafo)
    for k in range(len(grafo)):
        if not visited[k]:
            visited[k] = True
            persona += 1

            persona += recorrer(grafo, k, n, cola, visited, profundidad)

    print(persona)
```

Comment: Retorna el valor en cada función que lo usa.

Comment: Pero si la función que modifica el valor devuelve ya otra variable. Me he dado cuenta de que en Python muchas veces con una coma se pueden asignar varios valores. ¿También podría hacer algo como: return personas,profundidad y en la otra personas,profundidad=recorrido(……)?

Comment: Hombre!!! Esto es Python. Puedes hacer `return a,b,c` y luego recibir tres valores en una asignación `x, y, z = funcion()`

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de estructura es `grafo`?

Comment: Si no me equivoco, en la recursión el segundo argumento debería ser `v[0]` en vez de `v`.

Answer (score 0):

### Pasar por referencia

En Python las funciones reciben los objetos por referencia.
El `int` que recibe una función es el mismo objeto que tiene fuera.
Esto lo podemos comprobar comparando la dirección de memoria del objeto `int` dentro y fuera de la función:

```
def foo(a: int):
    return id(a)

i = 5000
print(id(i) == foo(i)) # imprime True
```

### `int` es inmutable

Una vez que defines un objeto `int` no lo puedes modificar.
Piensa que la clase `int` no tiene ningún método.
Es imposible que una variable `int` cambie de valor sin hacer una reasignación.
El incremento `i += 1` es equivalente a `i = i + 1`.
Como ves, estamos definiendo un nuevo objeto `i + 1` y estamos poniendo la variable `i` apuntando a este nuevo objeto.

Esto implica que, aunque tu función recibe el entero por referencia, de poco te sirve.
Es lo mismo que si te hubiera llegado por valor, ya que no lo puedes modificar ni dentro de la función ni fuera de ella.

### Simular `int` mutable

La forma más fácil en la que puedes simular un entero mutable es metiéndolo en un contenedor mutable.
En una tupla no te va a valer, pero puedes usar una lista.

```
def foo(i: list[int]):
    i[0] += 1

i = [5000]
foo(i)
print(i) # imprime [5001]
```

Esto es muy sencillo de hacer, pero tiene la clara desventaja de que hay que escribir la coletilla `[0]` cada vez que quieras acceder a su valor.
Además el código puede volverse confuso si no está correctamente comentado.

Siguiendo con el mismo concepto, puedes definir una clase

```
class MutableInt:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

Del mismo modo que antes cada vez que quieras usar el entero que contiene deberás acceder a su atributo.
Quizás puedes definir un método `__int__` para poder hacer la conversión.